# Using <apex:tab> loads standard style on page even though showHeader="false" sidebar="false" and standardStylesheets="false"

Tags: visualforce

I have made  `showHeader="false" sidebar="false"  standardStylesheets="false"`. But using `apex:tab` in the VF page makes the page take up standard salesforce css.

Here is the code in the page tag:

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false"  title="page" name="page" id="page">
```

[image]

Comment: Not able to attach image due to StackExchange Error

Comment: So whats happening and what you expect it to show ?

Comment: Standard css is being displayed when I am using apex tab. I do not want any css to be displayed for any of the salesforce VF components that I am using on the page